# CSS flexbox variable widths in same item (Shopify)

Tags: css, flexbox, sidebar

[Image of what I had, what it looks now and what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCziY.jpg)

Is there a way in CSS flexbox to expand an item (my prduct grid=brown) to full width after another item (my sidebar=grey) is finished? On the left side of the picture is what it looked like, before I implemented flex wrap, middle is what I have now with wrap, and right is what I want. Sometimes my sidebar is high, depending on the amount of filters that can be set. It would be nice to already see products next to the sidebar, but with full width after the sidebar is finished. 
My CSS code so far:

```
.flex-layout {
    display: flex;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-col1 {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.flex-col2 {
    flex: 2;
    flex-basis: 300px;
}
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

My shopify liquid template:

```
<div class="grid-uniform grid-link__container">
    <div class="flex-layout">
        <div class="col flex-col1">
                {% include 'collection-sidebar', sidebar-run-check %}
        </div>
        <div class="col flex-col2">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grid` here to define individual areas for items.

**Or**

Another simple approach is to *keep the first flex-item and remove the second one, and then use as the **background** for the flex container.*

You could keep the `width` property of first item if you want. **Or** set the `width` of flex-container to `100vw` and, set `flex-basis: 50%` and `flex-grow: 0` to the first flex-item to make it half the width of the container.

Comment: I try to replace flexbox with grid, but I only get the same results than with flexbox (or still even worse without wrap). All tutorials for "grid" show a rectangle form, I want to have "L" form, only inverted. So if my grid has four sections, in row 1 section 1 and 2, and in row 2 section 3 and 4, the sidebar should be in section 1, and the products should be in 2, 3 and 4.  grid-row-start and grid-column-start and end leads to rectangle form. Any ideas how to do that with grid?

Comment: Did you use `grid-area`? This is all you need. If this property seem confusing to you, this is a youtube video that helped me get the gist of it. Try it- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5KzBPUEgGQ . If it seems helpful, please leave your feedback by accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Sapinder. If I understand correctly, grid-area is a shorthand property for grid-row-start, grid-column-start, grid-row-end and grid-column-end. I can't get a different functional behaviour with grid-area than what I already have. I guess I just don't understand, sorry! Maybe you can give a short css example how to get a L- shaped form with grid? All what I find is that only rectangular forms are possible with grid, no L-forms.

Comment: you can't layout a **single** item in an _L_ shape. You were using the term **products** which led me think you want "_sidebar,product1,product2,product3_" in "_section1,section2,section3,section4_" respectively. But you can't make a container _L_ shaped simply because HTML only has rectangular blocks.

Comment: Oh that's a pity. But thanks for your help! I have a list of products that is filles in one div. That's why I wrote products. Sorry for the confusion, I thought I was clear.